# WordPress automatically redirects to login page

Tags: wordpress

I installed new WordPress Version 4.8.9, After i logged in its displaying dashboard and once i click any of the navigation tabs (settings, tools, pages ... etc) its redirecting to Login page.

**Redirected URL**

http://www.example.com/facilitatorform/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ffacilitatorform%2F%2F%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fpost_type%3Dpage&reauth=1

Comment: Hi, Please check your files and folder permissions. files must be of 644 permission and folder to 755

Comment: This issue got fixed after updated trolling slash in apache.

Comment: Can you give some more details?